# How to clear a text box when clicked on it?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using this JS to clear text box when user click on it, so this works fine and clears all the text box in the page, I want to clear only the search text box
 Search..
 How can I do that, Other text box should not be cleared and only this search text box should be cleared when I click on it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('input[type=text]').focus(function () {

                $(this).val('')
            });

        });
    </script>
```

And another question.

I have a panel with few text box, how can i set focus on a particular text box

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not the best idea to use `id` values since `.net` might change the `id` value in runtime

```
eg MainContent_txt_Name
```

you can do something like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" CssClass="myText" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {    
           $('.myText').click(function() {
                $(this).val('')
            });    
        });
</script>
```

Comment: If your javascript is on the same page and not an external file then there is no harm in using `ClientID` as in `$('#<%=(txt_name.ClientID)%>').click(.....);` This uses the unique client id so doesnt matter what .net does with changing it

Comment: but using a class will be more usable if need to apply the same thing to more than one text box

Comment: indeed, but the question related to clearing only the search text box

Answer (score 2):

Just select the `TextBox` via it's ID or another attribute

e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt_Search" runat="server" />
```

Then select the `TextBox` via it's unique client ID.

```
$('#<%=(txt_Search.ClientID)%>').focus(function() { $(this).val(''); });
```

Answer (score 2):

For clear value - `$('#yourTextBox').val('');`

For set focus - `$('#yourTextBox').focus();`

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$('input[type=text]')` do `$('search-box-id')`

Comment: missing the `#` in `$('#search-box-id')` ;)

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to specify id for the search box, try to inspect your element, or view source in order to get right id, because id is generated by ASP.NET web forms, or you can add custom attribute like rel="search-box"

so this is javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //for id
   $('#id_of_text_box').focus(function() { $(this).val(''););
  //for rel attribute
   $('input[rel="search-box"]').focus(function() {$(this).val(''););
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with HTML5's defaultvalue attribute falling back to this jquery approach:

http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/

Answer (score 0):

Another option, going down a slightly different route, use the JQuery textbox watermark component.
This has already been created to do just what you are asking and will repopulate when they click away from the textbox, but the backend will never see the value. Save you the hassle of doing it your self!

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/